# Text button on toolbar

Tags: .net, winforms, toolbar

I want to add a text button onto a WinForms toolbar (a standard button on a toolbar can contain an image only).

A textbox, a combobox can be easily added onto a toolbar but there is no option for a text button.

How can that be achieved?

**UPD** By 'text button' I mean the standard Windows button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [ToolStripControlHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripcontrolhost.aspx) to embed any control in your toolstrip:

```
Button button = new Button();
button.Text = "Standard Windows Button";
yourToolStrip.Items.Add(new ToolStripControlHost(button));
```

Answer (score 5):

Set [ToolStripItem.DisplayStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.displaystyle(v=vs.110).aspx) to [Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitemdisplaystyle(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
var toolStripButton = new ToolStripButton();
toolStripButton.DisplayStyle = ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Text;
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean by `text button` a button that not only contain image but also a text. So:

```
ToolBar toolbar = new ToolBar();

Button button = new Button();
button.Text = "Hi!";
button.Image = Image.FromFile("Your image path");//or from resource..

toolbar.Add(button);
this.Controls.Add(toolbar);
```

**Edit:** Since you mean `ToolStrip` you can do:

```
string text = "Hi";
Image image = Image.FromFile("Your image path");

ToolStripButton toolButton = new ToolStripButton(text, image);
toolButton.TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.Overlay;//or what ever you want to
toolStrip1.Items.Add(toolButton);
```

**Edit:**

> looks like a menu entry (a label which is highlighted when the mouse is over), not the standard button.

Unfortunately that what Microsoft provided. if you don't like it inherit the `ToolStripItem` and design your own.

Also note that you can use `toolButton.BackgroundImage` but it also will not give you the same effect that the ordinary `Button` will do.

Comment: It doesn't work, the `Add` method takes `ToolBarButton`, not `Button`. Also `ToolBar` is quite obsolete, `ToolStrip` has replaced it, and `ToolStrip` doesn't have a method for a simple button too.

Comment: I mean `toolbar.Controls.Add(button)`.

Comment: @Centro don't you mean [System.Windows.Forms.ToolBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolbar.aspx)?

Comment: It doesn't work as expected, it adds a button onto a toolbar over existing toolbar buttons, so the button location must be set to position it that is not very elegant. And it works that way only for the `ToolBar` toolbar, not for `ToolStrip` since it doesn't have the property `Controls`.

Comment: In my question I meant the `ToolStrip` class which should be used in WinForms instead of the old class `ToolBar`.

Comment: It looks like a menu entry (a label which is highlighted when the mouse is over), not the standard button.

Comment: Unfortunately that what Microsoft provided. if you don't like it inherit the ToolStripItem and design your own.